# Using logic when it comes to using results of one query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sub query below where it is able to ouput 11 teams randomly per team (1 GK, 4 DF, 4 MF and 2 FW).

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT pl.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pl.TeamID, pl.Position ORDER BY NEWID()) AS Rnk
    FROM(
        SELECT DISTINCT p.PlayerID, p.Position, p.PlayerWeighting, p.FirstName, p.Surname, t.TeamID, t.TeamAbbreviation, f.WeekNumber
        FROM dbo.Fixture f
        INNER JOIN dbo.League l ON f.LeagueID = l.LeagueID
        INNER JOIN dbo.Team t ON l.LeagueID = t.LeagueID
        INNER JOIN dbo.Player p ON t.TeamID = p.TeamID
        WHERE f.WeekNumber = 1) 
        pl) po
WHERE (po.position = 'GK' and po.rnk = 1) OR 
      (po.position = 'DF' and po.rnk <= 4) OR
      (po.position = 'MF' and po.rnk <= 4) OR
      (po.position = 'FW' and po.rnk <= 2)
```

Below is an example of what it output:

[image]

I then have a fixture query: SELECT * FROM dbo.Fixture and below is what it outputs:

[image]

Now this is where I am struggling for logic. I want to somehow link those players within their respective teams to pit against their opposition with a fixture week. The team with the highest player weighting (based on the 11 players playing that week), will win the game. I am not sure how to actually do this though. How can I combine these players with their fixtures is simply what I'm trying to ask so I can sum up their overall player weightings to determine the winner.

UPDATE:

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT pl.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pl.TeamID, pl.Position ORDER BY NEWID()) AS Rnk
    FROM(
        SELECT DISTINCT p.PlayerID, p.Position, p.PlayerWeighting, p.FirstName, p.Surname, t.TeamID, t.TeamAbbreviation, f.WeekNumber, SUM(PlayerWeighting)
        FROM dbo.Fixture f
        INNER JOIN dbo.Team t ON f.HomeTeamID = t.TeamID
        INNER JOIN dbo.Player p ON t.TeamID = p.TeamID
    WHERE f.WeekNumber = 1) pl) po
WHERE (po.position = 'GK' and po.rnk = 1) OR 
      (po.position = 'DF' and po.rnk <= 4) OR
      (po.position = 'MF' and po.rnk <= 4) OR
      (po.position = 'FW' and po.rnk <= 2) 
     GROUP BY TeamID
```

Comment: Why don't you `SUM(PlayerWeighting)` grouping by teamId on the first query and join that to `dbo.Fixture` by `HomeTeamID` or `AwayTeamID`?

Comment: Haven't really thought of that. I will give it a go. Put it as an answer so I can mark if it it's correct

Comment: Whaaaat!!! Arsenal's team ID is also 4th. HAHA!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you `SUM(PlayerWeighting)` grouping by `teamId` on the first query and join that to `dbo.Fixture` by `HomeTeamID or AwayTeamID`?
You'll get two rows by FixtureId

```
Select TeamID, SUM(PlayerWeighting) as TeamWeight
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM(
        SELECT pl.*,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pl.TeamID, pl.Position ORDER BY NEWID()) AS Rnk
        FROM(
            SELECT DISTINCT p.PlayerID, p.Position, p.PlayerWeighting, p.FirstName, p.Surname, t.TeamID, t.TeamAbbreviation, f.WeekNumber
            FROM dbo.Fixture f
            INNER JOIN dbo.League l ON f.LeagueID = l.LeagueID
            INNER JOIN dbo.Team t ON l.LeagueID = t.LeagueID
            INNER JOIN dbo.Player p ON t.TeamID = p.TeamID
            WHERE f.WeekNumber = 1) 
            pl) po
    WHERE (po.position = 'GK' and po.rnk = 1) OR 
          (po.position = 'DF' and po.rnk <= 4) OR
          (po.position = 'MF' and po.rnk <= 4) OR
          (po.position = 'FW' and po.rnk <= 2) ) as T
GROUP BY T.TeamID
```

Comment: Is it ok if you show a smaple code, it is not working because of invalid column which is weird

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Column 'dbo.Player.PlayerID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 22
No column name was specified for column 10 of 'po'.

Comment: @DazzleVision it looks like PlayerID is on the select list of the first query but you are grouping by TeamID. If you want to know the total weight of the team, you should not be selecting PlayerID

Comment: I updated my question to include current code. If I get rid of PLayerID then it says position field is invalid. I must be doing something wrong

Comment: @DazzleVision I updated the answer to show you how the query should look like IMHO

Comment: Ahhh, this was something I tried an hour ago where I tried to put another query for team weighting only at the top of the sub queries but messed up. Thank you very much.